# Best way to cater to two audiences on one website

Tags: design, web, audience

We are re-designing our corporate website and we need to cater to two distinct audiences: small business owners and large enterprises. The products we offer are the same for both audiences - but how we message the value of these products vary by audience. Management suggests making visitors choose who they are on the homepage, directing them to a personalized products page. But I'm skeptical of this approach. Is there a better way to "split" our website to address both audiences?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm not the biggest fan of multiple URL's/redirects unless it somehow meets your business needs and you'd like to track them separately. I've seen e-commerce sites show tiers/packages of their product offerings in a way that it only shows content of one at a time, defaulted to the one the the business is trying to drive sales for. I couldn't find any sites to give an example of what I wanted to suggest, but I made a quick mockup to give you an idea of what I had in mind.

Basically, near the top you could give your users the option to select what they identify as. From there on down you would display the relevant content. Hope that helps!

[image]